# Can't access VisualSVN from work with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I've installed VisualSVN but I can't access it remotely from work. It keeps giving me an errors saying something like error: `Repositry moved permanently to https://xxxxxx/svn please relocate`

On my VisualSVN app at home, the url is `https://xxxxx:8080/svn`

I tried `https://xxxxxx/svn` and it could not find the repository at all whilst the default one looked as if it was doing something but came up with that strange error.

Also, do I enter my static IP address in the "xxxxxx" instead of using the local host name of the pc running the VisualSVN server?

My local svn name is the name of my pc.

**Edit:** I've tried it locally on the browser and it worked but on TortoiseSVN it doesnt? At work it's the same thing, it works on my browser but not in TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 3):

`http://xxxx:8080/svn` is the base URL for a VisualSVN installation, it's **not** the URL of a repository. Your repository will be something like `http://xxxx:8080/svn/RepositoryName`

VisualSVN will show you a page for `http://xxxx:8080/svn`, that contains a list of all the repositories that you've created, hence it works for VisualSVN, but not for TortoiseSVN